# Where would you add '4' to the above binary search tree?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

[image: BST]

Where would you add '4' to the above binary search tree? And why?

A) A

B) B

C) C

D) Any of the above

My TA said it was just A but I'm thinking why can't it be all of the above

Comment: Ask yourself this: If you placed 4 at B or C and then needed to look for it, how would you find it?

Answer (score 1):

It is only A. Starting from root if your number is less than 5, go left branch. If your number is greater than 5 go right branch. Same process for every node.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: A

Options B and C both violate that BST property; i.e. the new key '4', whose value is smaller than '5', would end up in the right subtree of '5'. (The right subtree should have keys which are greater.)

Answer (score 1):

A [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) tree works by following the left child if the value you are searching for is less than the current node and right if it's greater until you find a node with desired value or the desired child is an empty tree (null).

So to test A, B or C:

- if 4 is greater than 5 and smaller than 8 and 6,   `B` is the correct answer.
- If 4 is greater than 5 and 8 but smaller than 42,  `C` is the correct answer.
- If 4 is smaller than 5 but greater than 3,  `A` is the correct answer.

In some silly field of mathematics or perhaps a parallel universe all these 3 might be correct at the same time, but besides that only one of these are correct with standard number theory.

Or from a search perspective (look at your tree from the root while reading this):

- 4 is smaller than 5 so go left.
- 4 is greater than 3 so go right
- right node empty, insert at `A`

Now where would `2` be inserted?